# Custom Javascript not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Browsed a lot, fiddled with it a lot. Came to the conclusion others may see the mistake that I am blind to.

The code is supposed to move the sidebar according to window height, sidebar height, content height, etc.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowheight = $(window).height();
    var identheight = $(".ident").height();
    var sidebarheight = $(".sidebar").height();
    var mainheight = $(".main").height();
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var diff = (((sidebarheight + 20) + identheight) - windowheight);
    var cur = ((sidebarheight + 20) + (pos - diff)) - 2;
    var max = (mainheight + 30);
    contentScroll();
$(window).resize(function(){
    windowheight = $(window).height();
    identheight = $(".ident").height();
    sidebarheight = $(".sidebar").height();
    mainheight = $(".main").height();
    pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    diff = (((sidebarheight + 20) + identheight) - windowheight);
    cur = (sidebarheight + 20) + (pos - diff);
    max = (mainheight + 30);
    contentScroll();
});
$(window).scroll(function (){
    pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    diff = (((sidebarheight + 20) + identheight) - windowheight);
    cur = (sidebarheight + 20) + (pos - diff);
    max = (mainheight + 30);
    contentScroll();
});
function contentScroll() {
if (sidebarheight < mainheight) {
        if (diff < identheight) {
            if (pos >= identheight) {
                $('.sidebar').css({
                    'margin-top'    :   (pos - identheight) + 'px'
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (pos >= diff && cur <= max) {
                $('.sidebar').css({
                    'margin-top'    :   (pos - diff) + 'px'
                });
            }
            if (pos <= diff) {
                $('.sidebar').css({
                    'margin-top'    :   '0px'
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

I'm aware of it not being perfect, it's still in the rough phase. It works perfectly fine in `FireFox`, but not in `chrome`. The function is being called (tested with alerts). It just doesn't do anything.

Probably something about `chrome` reading syntax different.

If anyone that see's my mistake would kindly point me to it, it's been too long for me to keep cracking my head open over this.

This is the mock-website in question: http://klok-bremen.de/fff/

Comment: So what is it supposed to do? Are any errors thrown?

Comment: Open the site in firefox to see what it should do. It's supposed to scroll the sidebar, depending on how big the window size, sidebar size, content size, etc. If any errors would be thrown I wouldn't be asking this question here, I guess. Thanks for the pointer, I checked the chrome console, nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't have to go to any other site to get a clear defintion of what the expected behavior of your code is. The question should be self contained including a proper problem statement and expected behavior

Comment: As for the errors , so many questions get posted here every day where people have not checked errors. If there aren't any, a simple statement to that fact will suffice

Comment: I edited it to explain what it's supposed to do. And yes I know what you're saying. I checked about 50 'My JS isn't working in Chrome' questions before this, but it became clear to me the mistakes aren't anything specific, rather something else every time. If you don't know what the little mistake is that's fine. Just hoping that somebody who see's what's wrong finds this question.

Comment: that's cool, not trying to bust balls...rather tune up what's needed for proper troubleshooting without a lot of wasted time

Comment: Like I said, I spent 1 hour on trying to find what's wrong, but I simply cannot find anything. I'm sure it's everyone's right to answer questions here and everyone's just the same to answer or disregard them. Don't like my question, look away.

Comment: It works after resizing the window and then scrolling. Just saying.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's something I haven't thought of doing. It'll surelely lead me to the mistake.

Comment: Can get rid of duplication by just triggering rezize on page load. Chain it to the resize handler. `$(window.).resize({/*code*/}).resize()`

Comment: Also cache your selectors for better performace since events you are using fire many times a second. Will cut down a significant amount of un needed DOM searches

Comment: maybe it isn't working when the document is ready because the images increase the elements height?  Try using $( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});  Instead of $(document).ready

Comment: Based on Roberts reply I have found a few brackets too many. I'll read into selector caching, I'm just starting with JQuery after all, so I don't know that much yet. The state right now is that it works offline, but not online yet. So I'll wait a little, sometimes it takes a while for a new JS to work online, from my experience.

Comment: If it works offline and not online that tells me it must be the images loading.  So using $( window ).load might work

Comment: There we go, it works. Thanks robert. Both the tip with the resizing and the $window.load have done the trick. If you would post it as a reply I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: browser will also cache scripts to speed next page load. Can disable caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $(window).load instead of $(document).ready because the parent elements' heights will change after the images load.